# spring-cloud-deployer - specifying maven remote repository URLs

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

Spring Cloud Data Flow - Cloudfoundry Server (v1.0.0.M4)

In working on trying to externalize configuration info in a properties file, and then use Spring Cloud Config Server to provide these environment settings at installation time, I've got a question about some of the values I would normally put a certain way in the YML manifest.

First, in a YML manifest, I might define them this way:

```
JAVA_OPTS: -Dhttp.keepAlive=false
MAVEN_REMOTE_REPOSITORIES_SNAPSHOTS_URL: <nexus url>
MAVEN_REMOTE_REPOSITORIES_RELEASES_URL: <another nexus url>
```

So how would I put these into a properties file? This is my guess:

```
java.opts=-Dhttp.keepAlive=false
maven.remote.repositories.snapshots.url=<nexus url>
maven.remote.repositories.releases.url=<another nexus url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to configure custom maven repository mirrors, please review this [section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/#_configure_maven_properties).

The Spring Cloud Deployer's [maven resolution](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/tree/master/spring-cloud-deployer-resource-maven) strategy looks for naming conventions defined in this section. One you have the right set of k/v pairs, you could then list them in property file or as env-var's.